# How to add data into SharePoint list using android?

Tags: java, android, sharepoint-2013

I know maybe its a silly question, but I could not found any solution ye to update the share-point list using android, any solution for that.

I tried to update share point list using postman right now with POST method but I' m getting "The HTTP header Content-Type is missing or its value is invalid." how to solve it.my value is below one

```
__metadata:'type': 'SP.Data.SomeListItem'
 subject:'AnyThing'
 CommentDocumentName:'Add'
 comment:'add Docs'
 role:'Customer'
 AppID:'1234'
 And header are=:
cookie:some value
Accept:application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest: some value
Content-Type:application/json;odata=verbose
```

Comment: gyes, any suggestion?.

Comment: in this context i want send some parameter to using rest API to update the list.